# How can I fill this buffer faster in clojure

Tags: opengl, optimization, clojure, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a function that will take a BufferedImage and return a ByteBuffer I can then use as an OpenGL texture. To do so, I've learnt that I must do some byte-shifting which is not really relevant to my question. It has to do with the BufferedImage values being ARGB and OpenGL wanting RGBA.

The function I'm trying to implement (from java) is this one:

```
public static ByteBuffer toByteBuffer(BufferedImage img){
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[img.getWidth()*img.getHeight()*4];
    for(int i = 0; i < img.getWidth()*img.getHeight(); i++){
        int value = img.getRGB(i%img.getWidth(), (i-(i%img.getWidth()))/img.getWidth() );
        byteArray[i*4] = (byte) ((value<<8)>>24); 
        byteArray[i*4+1] = (byte) ((value<<16)>>24);
        byteArray[i*4+2] = (byte) ((value<<24)>>24);
        byteArray[i*4+3] = (byte) (value>>24); 
    }
    return (ByteBuffer) ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(byteArray.length).put(byteArray).flip();
}
```

And this is my attempt with clojure:

```
(defn sub-byte [^long b ^long x]
  (unchecked-byte (-> x
    (bit-shift-left (* 8 b))
    (bit-shift-right 24))))


(defn bufferedimage->bytebuffer [^BufferedImage img]
  (binding [*unchecked-math* true] 
    (let [w (.getWidth img)
          h (.getHeight img)
          ^bytes arr (make-array Byte/TYPE (* 4 w h))]
      (loop [i 0]
          (let [img-i (mod i w)
                img-j (quot i w)
                value (.getRGB img img-i img-j)]
            (aset arr (* i 4)       (sub-byte 1 value))
            (aset arr (+ 1 (* i 4)) (sub-byte 2 value))
            (aset arr (+ 2 (* i 4)) (sub-byte 3 value))
            (aset arr (+ 3 (* i 4)) (sub-byte 0 value))
            (when (< (+ i 1) (* w h)) (recur (+ i 1)))
            ))
      (cast ByteBuffer (-> (ByteBuffer/allocateDirect (count arr))
                           (.put arr)
                           (.flip))))))
```

This takes 10 seconds to load a 512*512 tileset, which is completely unacceptable. I'm trying to make this run in way less than one second.

Note that the part that's taking all the time is the loop.

I might as well mention that those times are taken using the REPL.

Also, note that I'm well aware I can use java for the performance-critical parts of my code, so this is more of a theoretical question so I can learn how to optimize my clojure code.

Comment: You could use `clojure.core/time` to measure which parts of your code take the most time.

Comment: I already did. From my post: "Note that the part that's taking all the time is the loop.".

Comment: [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) is a better way to benchmark.  In general, `map`, `reduce` and `filter` are probably better choices for speed and more idiomatic than `loop/recur`.

Comment: I thought map, reduce and filter would actually be worse than a tail-call optimized loop because of the overhead of building the lazy-seq, isn't that so?

Comment: Why are you doing this with a byte[] at all? ByteBuffer exists specifically so you don't have to do so many indirections fiddling around with stuff on the heap. Allocate a correct-sized ByteBuffer at the start of the function, and just call `.put` on it many times, rather than making a byte[] and then having to do a bunch of arithmetic to figure out the right offsets!

Comment: My above suggestion won't particularly speed things up by itself, since as the answers say, the real expense is you're using reflection and boxing, but it will improve upon things once you've gotten that under control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with solution using function is revealed when you set `*warn-on-reflection*` to `true`:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

When you load your code, the compiler will tell you that your `sub-byte` function returns `Object` and it cannot resolve statically a matching method.

```
Reflection warning, web_app/so.clj:26:11 - call to static method aset on clojure.lang.RT can't be resolved (argument types: [B, int, java.lang.Object).
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use a type hint for `byte` return value on your function as only `long` and `double` primitives are supported as return types:

```
(defn sub-byte ^byte [^long b ^long x]
  (unchecked-byte (-> x
                      (bit-shift-left (* 8 b))
                      (bit-shift-right 24))))

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only long and double primitives are supported, compiling:(web_app/so.clj:7:1)
```

You might try to hint `^long` as the return type but then the hinted result type is not what your function body returns (`byte`):

```
(defn sub-byte ^long [^long b ^long x]
  (unchecked-byte (-> x
                      (bit-shift-left (* 8 b))
                      (bit-shift-right 24))))

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched primitive return, expected: long, had: byte, compiling:(web_app/so.clj:7:1)
```

You can however have your function to return `long` but then you have to wrap it everywhere with `unchecked-byte` - this way you eliminate all reflections warnings:

```
(defn sub-byte ^long [^long b ^long x]
  (-> x
      (bit-shift-left (* 8 b))
      (bit-shift-right 24))))

(unchecked-byte (sub-byte ...))
```

Another solution is to use macro as you already found out which will avoid any issues with function calls and its return types.

Comment: Thank you, so the problem was not on function calls but rather on the function returning the byte wrapped in an object. I'll keep that in mind and be sure to turn on that warn-on-reflection option. Thanks!

Comment: Recent versions of Clojure do support [byte and bytes hints](http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#TypeAliases). You could also use [bytes casting](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bytes)

Comment: @kawas44 Yes, Clojure does support `byte` and `bytes` hints but the issue is that Clojure functions can return only `long` or `double` for the primitive types. They don't support `int` or `byte` or other primitive return types (as the compiler message clearly states: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only long and double primitives are supported`).

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the time from 10s to 173ms by converting sub-byte into a macro:

```
(defmacro sub-byte [b x]
  `(unchecked-byte (-> ~x
    (bit-shift-left (* 8 ~b))
    (bit-shift-right 24))))
```

It appears that the performance issues had to do with all the function calls.

I find it quite intriguing though, I didn't think function calls would be so inefficient in Clojure. Also, I thought the compiler was performing  inlining optimizations under the hood for me.

Although I've found out the "what", I'm not aware of the "why", so I'll be accepting an answer that explains what's going on rather than mine.